# Merge 2d bool arrays C

Tags: c

I have two bool arrays :

```
const int gridsize = 45; 
bool grid[gridsize+1][gridsize+1];
bool grid2[gridsize+1][gridsize+1];
```

How can i obtain third array (grid3) that contains true fields of both of them?

Comment: Why are you using `gridsize+1`? This can be confusing later.

Comment: "*How can i obtain third array (grid3) that contains true fields of both of them?*" by defining it and writing the appropriate code to assign the correct values.

Comment: Also C and C++ are different languages and there are only rare cases where tagging a question by both languages makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Loop over third array and assign true if any of previous two array contain true at that position: `grid3[i][j] = grid[i][j] || grid2[i][j]`